# why does docker throw an error when I delete an image that is referred by a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm studying Docker but I got curious about an error docker throws.
When I try deleting an image which has been referred by a container, Docker throws an error saying

## Error mesage

`Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "hello-world" (must force) - container 6a2e5242c2ac is using its referenced image fce289e99eb9`

I thought if I remove the image, there would be a problem when I start the container again, but there was no problem at all in starting the container again.

## Here's some steps to describe my question.

`docker run hello-world`

container will run well and some messages will show up in the terminal.

`docker ps -a`

there will be a stopped container whose image name is "hello-world" and it will have an ID

`docker rmi -f hello-world`

without "-f", Docker will throw an error with removing it.

`docker start -i {ID of the CONTAINER}`

Even though we removed the base image of the container, the container works well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zjlG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgg9U.png)

## Here are my questions.

1. Is the error just to warn the image has been used for making a container?
2. If the answer is "NO", what problem can happen after removing the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only provide a birds-eye view of why this is necessary, hopefully others can elaborate.

Docker uses read-only layers of relative differences to build a final state. Running a container designates a process that records changes relative to the image. However, in order for this to work Docker must know what the base image and its contents are. This is why the image must remain available.

The way I like to think about this is how versioning systems like Git work. Your local changes are displayed only because a fixed reference (a local repository) is available.

An example: Suppose an image contains `file.txt`. The container process starts and changes the first line of that file. This change is not stored by altering the original file, but it is recorded as a diff. 
When your container process reads the file, it reads the original file from the image and what changes have been made from the container. If the image would not be available, docker can not know what the current contents of the file are, because it only knows what changed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. But I don get what you mean after "However" you said.

I'm aware of there are read-only layers and there are writable layers at the top of containers' layers

Can you give me more detailed explanations?

Comment: Added an example.